# javascript function not being called in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, onmouseover, onmouseout

So i have this code:

```
<?php
$mysql_host='localhost';
$mysql_user='root';
$mysql_password="CAN'T KNOW MY PASWORD!!!1!";

mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password);
@mysql_select_db('galaxall');
?>

<style>
.clap{
  background-color:red;
}
</style>

<p style="background-color:rgb(2,2,2)">
<div style="background-color:rgb(250,250,250);padding-bottom:3%;margin-right:20%">
  <?php
    $hello='hello everybody!!! &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;I\'m d boss!';
    $img='<img src="b5.jpg">';


    $query="SELECT * FROM `comments`  ";
    $results = mysql_num_rows($query);

    echo  $results;

    if($is_query_run=mysql_query($query) )
    {
      $results = mysql_num_rows($is_query_run);

      echo "Number of comments:<font style='font-weight:bold;'>$results".'<p style="font-weight:bold;" onclick="alert("hello")">'.'</font>';

      while($query_execute=mysql_fetch_assoc($is_query_run) )
      {
        echo $query_execute ['Comment'].'<br>'.'<br>'.'<br>'."<a href='' class='clap'>.<img src='clap4.png' width='3%' height='3%'>.'&npsp;'.'&npsp;'.'&npsp;'.'&npsp;'.'&npsp;'
        .'Respond'</a>".'<p style="background-color:white;padding-bottom:1%;padding-left:3.5%;padding-top:1%;margin-left:0%;border:1px solid grey;border-radius:5%;box-shadow:2px 2px 2px #999;margin-right:25%; id="comment" >';
      }
    }
    else
    {
      echo"Sorry, something went wrong...";
    }
  ?> 
</p>
<script>
 var d = document.getElementsByClassName("clap");
 var c = document.getElementById("comment");

 function mouseOver() {
   d.style.backgroundColor = "red";
 }

 function mouseOut() {

   d.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
 }

 c.onmouseover = mouseOver();
 c.onmouseout = mouseOut();
```

What happens is that it selects all the items for a row known as comment then beautifies each of the comments(items from each row of comments) and an image appears on each of the comments (like and dislike icon) everything is good except that I don't want the images to show until the mouse hovers over the comment paragraph with id="comment".But what happens is that immediately i load the page,the comments are  already highlighted which is something I want to happen  WHEN the mouse hovers over the paragraph 'comments' and when I try to hover and 'unhover(if there is a word like that:-))' over the comments,it DOESNT become blue ,but according to my code,it is supposed to become blue `onmouseout` and red `onmouseover`.I've checked the console of my browser (chrome) and it says

```
10:45:19.526 comments_gxx58.php:50 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined
    at mouseOver (comments_gxx58.php:50)
    at comments_gxx58.php:60
```

And In don't know what that means....

Note:I've also tried to put the onmouseover property directly inline as

`<p style="background-color:white;padding-bottom:1%;padding-left:3.5%;padding-top:1%;margin-left:0%;border:1px solid grey;border-radius:5%;box-shadow:2px 2px 2px #999;margin-right:25%; id="comment" onmouseover="mouseOver()">'`

I've tried all I can

Please help

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array of objects. You can't just set a style on the entire collection, you need to loop over it.

Comment: Please do not use tags that are completely unrelated

Comment: what tag was unrelated?

Answer (score -1):

It's because a jQuery object doesn't have a style property.

try this:

```
d.css.("backgroundColor", "red");
```

f you wanted to use the DOM API, you could do a traditional DOM selection:

```
document.getElementById("surmenu").style.backgroundColor="red";
```

Comment: Please don't be offended but what made you think I was using jquery?I clearly said javascript